# hiding x-axes labels with 0 values on a bar chart

Tags: chart.js

I have a map (K, V) of dates and values that I'd like to display in a bar chart using chart.js. Date being on the x-axis and the count/number on the y-axis. The dates are sporatic so I want to hide all of the dates that don't have values (i.e. count = 0). In other words, I only care about showing dates that have data.

I'm kind of new to chart.js so I've tried messing with some of the scales chart options but not finding great api documentation of what all of the options are to configure.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to filter your data before passing it into `chart.js` with function [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: my data is just 4 key value pairs, for example

map = new Map([ [04/01/2014, 53],  [10/08/2014, 175], [04/01/2015, 126], [10/08/2014, 50] ])

but my chart has a tick/label for every date in between